# hello, i want to know how i can remove the first element of my list

Tags: list, removechild

i have tried a lot but nothing worked, i am new in this and i am learning myself.
this is what i have
can anyone help me please?

{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

```
<h1>hello, {{ user.username }}!</h1>
{% for post in posts %}
<hr>


<div> Toegang tot lijst!</div>


<input type='text' id='input' />
<input type='button' value='add to list' id='add' />
<input type='button' value='remove from list' id='verwijder'/>


<hr>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {
        var text = document.getElementById("input").value; 
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.textContent = text
        document.getElementById("lijst").appendChild(li);
        document.getElementById("input").value = ""; // clear the value 
    }
</script>

<center>
    <ul id='lijst' style="list-style-type:none;">
        <li> <b>Volgorde</b></li> 
    </ul>
</center>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("verwijder").onclick = function{
        var list = document.getElementById("lijst");   
        list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
</script>
{% endfor %}
```

{% endblock %}

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using some jQuery. With jQuery you can get a list of all - let's say you used the following div and class : `<div class=customItem>`.

Your button click event would look something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("verwijder").onclick = function{
    let list = $("#verwijder").find(".customItem);
    // The following statement references by index and will always get the first object in the list
    list[0].remove();
    list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
</script>
```

Don't forget to import the jQuery library:  https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```